# Parser Error Message: The file '/TestSite/Default.aspx.cs' does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Short story.
This site was created by a friend of mine, who did not know that much C# or asp. And was firstly created in VS 2k3. When i converted it to VS 2k8 these errors started to crop up, there was also other issues with compiling that i managed to sort out ( Seemed to be released to VS 2k8 wanted design files )

Error message gotten:

> An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The file '/TestSite/Default.aspx.cs' does not exist.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  `<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
>   CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="GuildStats._Default" %>`
>
> Line 2:
>
> Line 3:  `<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">`

Defaults.aspx.cs

```
namespace GuildStats
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
```

Defaults.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="GuildStats._Default" %>
```

Site.master.cs

```
namespace GuildStats
{
    public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage { }
}
```

Site.master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="GuildStats.Site" %>
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

In `Default.aspx` change `CodeFile` to `CodeBehind`. You'll probably have to do the same for the `Site.master`.

See: [CodeFile and Code-Behind](http://www.ddj.com/windows/187202007)

Comment: How does that link address this issue?  It mentions the CodeFile attribute, but not CodeBehind.  MSDN documentation states CodeBehind is obsolete, so I'm trying to figure out why switching back to CodeBehind is a solution.

Answer (score 18):

Web Site projects use CodeFile, Web Application projects use CodeBehind.
CodeFile requires the source file, it is compiled on the fly when the page is loaded, CodeBehind requires the compiled code.

My guess is that your problem was created when you changed your project type from a WebApp to a Web Site or vice-versa. If you do this, you have to manually change the directives in the existing files, new files will have the right directive automatically.