# Failing to load a published ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net

I'm being driven completely out of my mind trying to publish a simple ASP.NET project, using MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express to a standard Windows 7 installation of IIS.
I have scoured the internet looking for solutions, and I haven't found anything that has worked.
I really hope someone can help!

I developed a page that I was trying to publish, and it worked fine when I ran it from Visual Studio. However when I used the publish facility (to file-system) within Visual Studio - into my Windows 7 IIS website, I got an error message suggesting my Page directive was incorrect.

I decided to start from the absolute basics and try to publish the contents of a default project and see how I got on with that, but this appears to have the same problem. Here are the steps I went through.

I created a new project which I named ‘pea5’. By default the ‘ASP.NET Web Application’ project type is created with a master page, and an **Account** folder containing some login control pages – neither of which I want, so I deleted the **Account** folder, the **masterpage.aspx**, and the About.aspx page.
This required that I remove the MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" from the Page directive in the remaining **Default.aspx** mark-up, and I also had to remove the encapsulating Content tags from the mark-up too, because they only work in master-page configurations. This left me with the following in my **Default.aspx** mark-up file...

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="pea5._Default" %>
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">www.asp.net</a>.
    </p>
    <p>
        You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
            title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
    </p>
```

The codebehind file contained only an empty Page_Load method, as follows...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace pea5
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I also trimmed out the authentication, membership, profile and roleManager sections from my **web.config** file, as I didn’t expect I’d need those anymore having previously deleted the login pages. So my **web.config** file looked like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I ran the project, the **Default.aspx** page loaded perfectly.

I then published my project (choosing the filesystem option) into my IIS folder structure, and when I browsed to the **Default.aspx** page using IE, I got the following error.

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'pea5._Default'.

Why would this work perfectly well in Visual Studio, but not in IIS?!
Anyway.
I found another stackoverflow post [Parser Error Message: The file '/TestSite/Default.aspx.cs' does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538719/parser-error-message-the-file-testsite-default-aspx-cs-does-not-exist) which suggested I would need to change the CodeBehind setting in the Page directive of the markup.

So I changed...

```
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"
```

...to...

```
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"
```

After another publish, and refresh of my page, I then got the following error in IE.

> Parser Error Message: The file '/Default.aspx.cs' does not exist.

I found this message rather strange. Surely having published my code into a DLL file in the bin folder, I would no longer need the codebehind in order to load the page.
Sure enough, when I copied the codebehind file **Default.aspx.cs** into my published folder on IIS, the page then worked.

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

With this discovery, I was then able to revisit the page I originally developed, begrudgingly accepting the fact that I would have to upload my codebehind file in order to get my page to work.
However this presented a new problem, because the default page on my original solution references a class...

```
clsLists myords = new clsLists();
myords.LoadList();
```

...and the page returned this error message in IE...

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'clsLists' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I assumed I would also have to add my **clsLists.cs** file to my published folder in order for this to be successfully referenced, so I copied that in too, but I just got the message above again.

If anyone can shed any light on this, I would be eternally grateful.
I am happy to provide any more info on my configuration if required.

Many Thanks,

Dean.

Answer (score 0):

First going back to your original solution (code behind) make sure your .dll is in the bin directory (root), might be excluded. Also You can try to convert your site to an application (in inetmgr -> right click on your site -> convert to application).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response.
I have checked, and the DLL is present.
I would prefer not customise the site in its entirety, because there are lots of other folders on the site with different themed content (all classic asp) and everything currently works.