# Server Error in Sub Directory Application - Parser Error Message: File Master does not exist

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, master-pages

I recently uploaded a Web Application to our Windows 2008 R2 Web Server.

After adding the site to IIS7.5 and configuring all I was aware of, I went to browse it:

[image: browse]

I get the security certificate warning, because we have not purchased a certificate yet. I acknowledge the warning, get prompted for (and enter) my Windows credentials, then get slapped with this **Server Error** that tells me `The file '/apps/sub/codebase.Master' does not exist.`

[image: master missing]

Let me point this out. Using **Explore** I can show you that the file **codebase.Master** does exist, but it is up one level from the **/sub** folder:

[image: location of codebase master]

In an effort to get IIS 7.5 to understand that this sub app needs to use the Master Page in the parent folder, I have tried the following:

- Set Application Pool to .NET 4, Classic, with 32-bit support, and **Application Pool Identity**
  [image: pic]
- Set Folder to Application
- Reset (start & stop) the Application Pool
- Granted permission to ASP.NET account
  [image: asp.net account]
- Master Page's Web.config file requires Windows Authentication:
- Sub Folder pages using Master Page have their own Web.config files that only include separate database connection strings:
- Tried Microsoft's [Walkthrough Step 3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehszf8ax(v=vs.100).aspx) (**virtualpath** trick & manually defining Master Page)
  `<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/Master1.master" %>`
- Checked that the Master directive uses [CodeBehind and not CodeFile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/538815/153923)

Perhaps this is worth noting, but I'm not sure:

When I browse the Root Application, none of the CSS styling or Javascript works. In the `<head>` tag of the Master Page, these are defined as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/apps.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Scripts/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

All of this also works from my PC while testing through Visual Studio 2010's debug mode.

I am obviously missing a key step.

### Does anyone see what might be missing?

Comment: Did you try giving relative path like <%@ MasterType virtualpath="../codebase.master" %>?

Comment: @PankajKapare: Honestly, not until you mentioned it. When I make that change, I get this new error: **"The virtual path '/apps/codebase.Master' maps to another application, which is not allowed."** I am going to go research that now...

Comment: Does your folders "app" and "sub" part of one web application in IIS or configured as seperate applications in IIS?

Comment: Looking at images in question I am guessing "sub" folder is also configured as application. If its not meant to be application then please remove it and fallback to <%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/codebase.master" %>

Comment: I would test removing the **APPLICATION** setting feature, but I don't see how. Do I have to delete the folder and add it again?

Comment: On "Sub" application right click and select "remove" option. Thats it.

Comment: Awesome! Poor choice of wording from Microsoft. Now, I just need to find out how to get my CSS to working.